# How can I (or can I even) transfer iTunes/App store credit from one Apple ID to another?

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

How can I transfer my $0.49 on my apple ID to my family members $0.54 on her apple ID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, as of this moment this is not possible!

Comment: There is no need to add signatures etc. at the end of answers, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior for details.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the option to transfer money between the accounts is not available online.

You can always call them and see if they will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to transfer balances that exist on an iTunes account / Apple ID.

You can spend it down or let it sit there as a credit.

Answer (score -3):

You can send it as a gift from one account to another. On the bottom of the App Store there is a button that says send gift, select that and fill in details and you should be able to send it.

Comment: Can you add some explanation on how to do that?

Comment: You can gift an item (Music, App although weirdly not books), but not credit.